# iOS 10 : How can I get a call end event using objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios10

I'm trying to get a call status in iOS 10.
Now I got a call connection event but I can't get a call disconnection event.
My code is like this:

```
self.callObserver = [[CXCallObserver alloc] init];
[callObserver setDelegate:self queue:nil];

...

- (void)callObserver:(CXCallObserver *)callObserver callChanged:(CXCall *)call {
    if (call.hasConnected) {
        NSLog(@"********** voice call connected **********/n");
        // perform necessary actions
    } else if(call.hasEnded) {
        NSLog(@"********** voice call disconnected **********/n");
    }
}
```

How can I get a call disconnection event?

Comment: I am not able to get any event out of this code... :(

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Call Kit, but my first thought, looking at your code, is this: Perhaps the problem is that a call that has ended has also (previously) connected.

If that is true, then your `if(call.hasEnded)` would never run, because you said `else if`. This would not be an `else`; *both* `hasConnected` *and* `hasEnded` would be true.